# Can't change desktop environment Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: gnome, 15.10, xfce, environment

I installed xfce and gnome desktop environments and I don't see a way how to change it.

On log in screen there isn't any option, does anybody have similar problem?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install XFCE?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the Unity logo in the upper side of the login credential box you should be able to switch between installed desktop environments.